# How to do sequencial HTTP calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

I have a couple of APIs I need to call to collect and merge information.
I make the first API call and, based on the result, I make several calls to the second one (in a loop).
Since http requests are asynchronous I'm loosing the information. By the time the second step is finished the server (nodejs) already sent the response back to the client.

I've already tried to, somehow, use the callback functions. This managed to keep the response to the client waiting but the information of the second call was still lost. I guess somehow the variables are not being synchronized.
I also did a quick test with away/async but my Javascript mojo was not enough to make it run without errors.

```
/* pseudo code */
function getData(var1, callback){

url= "http://test.server/bla?param="+var1;

request.get(url, function (error, response, body){
var results = [];
  for(var item of JSON.parse(body).entity.resultArray) {  
     var o = {};
     o['data1'] = item.data1;
     o['data2'] = item.data2;
     o['data3'] = item.data3;

     getSecondStep(o, function(secondStepData){
       //console.log("Callback object");
       //console.log(o);
       o['secondStepData'] = secondStepData;
     });
     results.push(o);
  }
  callback(results);
});
}

function getSecondStep(object, callback){

  url = "http://othertest.server/foobar?param=" + object.data1;
  request.get(url, function (error, response, body){
    var results = [];
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      for(var item of JSON.parse(body).object.array) {
        var o = {}
        o['data4'] = item.data4;
        o['data5'] = item.data5;
        results.push(o);
      }
      callback(results);
    }
});
}
```

What I would like is to be able to collect all the information into one JSON object to return it back to the client.
The client will then be responsible for rendering it in a nice way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the async / await pattern with the [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) library.

This makes API calls really easy to make and the code is cleaner when using this pattern.

In the example below I'm just calling a httpbin API to generate a UUID but the principle applies for any API.

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

async function callAPIs() {
    let firstAPIResponse = await rp("https://httpbin.org/uuid", { json: true });
    console.log("First API response: ", firstAPIResponse);

    // Call several times, we can switch on the first API response if we like.
    const callCount = 3;
    let promiseList = [...Array(callCount).keys()].map(() => rp("https://httpbin.org/uuid", { json: true }));
    let secondAPIResponses = await Promise.all(promiseList);

    return { firstAPIResponse: firstAPIResponse, secondAPIResponses: secondAPIResponses };
}

async function testAPIs() {
    let combinedResponse = await callAPIs();
    console.log("Combined response: " , combinedResponse);
}

testAPIs();
```

In this simple example we get a combined response like so:

```
{
    { 
        firstAPIResponse: { uuid: '640858f8-2e69-4c2b-8f2e-da8c68795f21' },
        secondAPIResponses: [ 
            { uuid: '202f9618-f646-49a2-8d30-4fe153e3c78a' },
            { uuid: '381b57db-2b7f-424a-9899-7e2f543867a8' },
            { uuid: '50facc6e-1d7c-41c6-aa0e-095915ae3070' } 
        ] 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd go with `let promises = []; ... promises.push(rp( ...)) ... let secondAPIResponses = await Promise.all(promises);` so that these requests can run in paralell.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice way to go. !

Comment: Perfect!
I first tried to just "make it work" with the counters but the shared objects became all messed up. With this solution I actually made it work. As it's only a POC I'm not parallelizing anything but that should be a simple improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `callback` of first function only when all the second `callback` functions have been called. Try this changes:

```
function getData(var1, callback) {

    url = "http://test.server/bla?param=" + var1;

    request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
        var results = [],count=0;
        var arr = JSON.parse(body).entity.resultArray;
        for (let [index, value]  of arr.entries()) {
            var o = {};
            o['data1'] = item.data1;
            o['data2'] = item.data2;
            o['data3'] = item.data3;

            getSecondStep(o, function (secondStepData) {
                //console.log("Callback object");
                //console.log(o);
                o['secondStepData'] = secondStepData;

                results[index] = o;
                count++;
                if (count === arr.length) {
                    callback(results);
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `if (results.length === arr.length)` will be true after the last `results.push(o);` and before the first `o['secondStepData'] = secondStepData;` has been executed.

Comment: True. Made the changes @Thomas

Comment: now you only have to ensure that the order is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go over to a library that supports promises (eg: https://github.com/request/request-promise) as the code becomes much easier to deal with than the callback method.

Your code would look something like:

```
function getData(var1){
    var url = "http://test.server/bla?param="+var1;
    return request.get(url).then(result1 => {
        var arr = JSON.parse(body).entity.resultArray;
        return Promise.all( arr.map(x => request.get("http://othertest.server/foobar?param=" + result1.data1)))
                     .then(result2 => {
                              return {
                                data1: result1.data1,
                                data2: result1.data2,
                                data3: result1.data3,
                                secondStepData: result2.map(x => ({data4:x.data4, data5:x.data5}))
                             }
                      })
    });
}
```

And usage would be

```
getData("SomeVar1").then(result => ... );
```

Comment: The return data is not same as expected. All the `secondStepData ` is array of all the `second` calls

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling the callback while you still have async calls going on. Several approaches are possible, such us using async/await, or reverting to Promises (which I would probably do in your case).

Or you can, well, call the callback only when you have all the information available. Pseudo code follows:

```
function getData(var1, callback){

  url= "http://test.server/bla?param="+var1;

  request.get(url, function (error, response, body){
    var results = [];
    var items = JSON.parse(body).entity.resultArray;
    var done = 0, max = items.length;
    for(var item of items) {  
       var o = {};
       o['data1'] = item.data1;
       o['data2'] = item.data2;
       o['data3'] = item.data3;

       getSecondStep(o, function(secondStepData){
         //console.log("Callback object");
         //console.log(o);
         o['secondStepData'] = secondStepData;
         results.push(o);
         done += 1;
         if(done === max) callback(results);
       });
    }
});
}
```

(note that since this is pseudo code, I am not checking for errors or handling a possible empty result from `request.get(...)`)